# Send errors in Django to Sentry asynchronously with Celery to avoid Sentry's error droping

Tags: python, django, celery, sentry

I'm using Sentry for error capturing and reporting in Django (with logging config in settings.py). However, Sentry doesn't capture errors when I send lots of errors in a short time (the free version phenomena). One solution is putting them in a queue and send them async with brokers like Celery. My questions are:
1- Is there any other solution to capture all errors.
2- How can I send the errors to Celery and then to Sentry.

I want to handle it in settings.py to avoid cascading to all files.

Comment: sentry is free and open source, I suggest you to setup your own sentry server

Comment: Can you provide some help if you have done it? I don't want to start from 101 Sentry.

Comment: Thank you for copy/pasting sentry's documentation for me.